# Converting values (kg to lbs) in MVVM pattern

Tags: mvvm

I am building an app that can track weight. I allow the user to select their unit preference of kg or lbs. I want to keep the data in the DB standard (kg) so if the user selects lbs as their preference I need the data converted from kg to lbs in the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This conversion can be handled very easily in the ViewModel.

This is one of the huge advantages of having a ViewModel - you can have easily testable logic, such as conversion between units, which stays completely separate from the user interface code.

Comment: After reading some Josh Smith I decided that value converters were not the way to go. Specifically Josh says that the View Model is just a Value Converter on Steroids. Thanks

Comment: @John: Yeah, that's kind of my thinking here.  You have a lot more control within the ViewModel, including (at least easily) converting using many properties, not just the one in question...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use it Coverter Property of DataBinding and resolve it by XAML.

```
DataBinding = { Binding Path = YourProperty,Converter = {StaticResource YourConverter}}
```

YourConverter must implement the IValueConverter inferface ([msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)) and has to be declare as Resource.

I would prefer this approach because keep the conversion logic on the View Side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing we are in WPF. Use a [Binding Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) and create an object implementing IValueConverter doing the proper configured conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can explain to do this is to use a custom converter interface.  Instead of talking on I'll just zap you an example.

```
    private IConverter<Double, Double> weightConverter = new KgToLbsConverter();
    private double _weight;
    public double Weight
    {
        get
        {
            return weightConverter.ConvertFrom(_weight);
        }

        set
        {
            _weight = weightConverter.ConvertTo(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Weight);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a simple converter contract.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The source Type</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="R">The target Type.</typeparam>
    public interface IConverter<T, R>
    {
        R ConvertFrom(T value);
        T ConvertTo(R value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a converter to change Kg to Lbs and vice versa
    /// </summary>
    public class KgToLbsConverter : IConverter<Double, Double>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// From Kg to Lbs.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The weight in Kg.</param>
        /// <returns>The weight in Lbs.</returns>
        public double ConvertFrom(double value)
        {
            return value / 2.2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// From Lbs to Kg.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">The weight in Lbs.</param>
        /// <returns>The weight in Kg.</returns>
        public double ConvertTo(double value)
        {
            return value * 2.2;
        }
    }
```

Using this you could make can any converters you want, and then let the user select from concrete implementations.

Note: The reason I prefer this over converters is view models may need to know what conversion mode is active and how to work with them, this adds quite a bit of flexibility.  When you need a single conversion for a V-VM relationship then IValueConverter is the way to go, but for your scenario, this is easier to maintain and to extend.